# How to request disk from Softlayer with encryption set to no?

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

The bosh deploy command used to be able to request disk from Softlayer with the following defined in yml file:

```
disk_pools:
- disk_size: 20480
  name: dp_20G
```

Up until recently it will return a disk with encryption set to no so bosh can mount the disk.  But now it is returning a disk with encryption set to yes and bosh can't mount the disk.  I thought I would add the following to get the old behavior:

```
  cloud_properties:
    encryption: no
```

But the above still returns disk with encryption set to yes.  Is there a way to request disk with encryption set to no so bosh can mount it?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with Bosh commands, but the following might help you.

If your disk is a NFS volumen, the problem isn’t the “encryption” exactly, but the fact that the mount point has changed and Bosh hasn’t updated it.

If it is a Block storage, there is no reason you are not able to mount it. On this case I recommend you to submit a ticket to SoftLayer in order to get further assistance (try to provide info like the storage id).